# Getting jEdit to show all schematic variable assignments

Tags: isabelle

Is there an easy way to get jEdit to show a list of all schematic variable assignments at a certain point in an Isabelle proof?

Comment: A kind-of workaround is activating show_types (``supply [[show_types]]``). In the variable section, the variables starting with question marks are exactly the schematic variable of the goal.